# How to call script using another script located in a different directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to call a script using another script located in a different directory but some errors(related to the location of the file) appear. To ilustrate my problem, I will show an example.

Imagine that I have a folder called 001, and inside the folder has another 3 subfolders called A , B and C. Furthermore, inside the folder 001 there are a script called `script`.
In each subfolder A, B  and C I has the files lista, listb and listc respectively

When I execute the `script`, the output are printed and every is OK. 
But I am interested to call this script using the `motherscript`, but I get the error.

```
cat: A/lista: No such file or directory
cat: B/listb: No such file or directory
cat: C/listc: No such file or directory
```

Ilustration of directories

```
   folder
     |_ motherscript
     |_ 001
         |_ A
         |   |_lista
         |_ B
         |   |_listb
         |_ C
         |   |_listc
         |_ script
```

script

```
 cat A/lista B/listb C/listc > output
```

motherscript

```
 ./001/script
```

lista

```
1 
2
3
```

listb

```
4
5
6
```

listc

```
7
8
9
```

output

```
1 
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: paths are not relative to the other scripts.  If you invoke `script` as `./001/script` and do not have anything in there that changes directory your path to, say, `lista` is `001/A/lista` not just `A/lista`

Answer (score 3):

You use relative paths in `script`. So, you need to change your present working directory accordingly in `motherscript` before calling `script`.

```
# motherscript

cd 001
./script
```